# Using dplyr how can i negative a value in a data frame based off an indicator

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains an indicator and a value, whenever that indicator = "X", i want to negatate the corpsonding value.

I can do this easily using the which, finding the indecies and negating, but would like to use dplyr

Comment: Please take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Regarding your question... try something like `df %>% mutate(value=ifelse(indicator=='X', -value, value))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(value = case_when(indicator == 'X' ~ -1 * value, TRUE ~ value))
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering you have a dataframe as this -

```
df <- data.frame(indicator = c('X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'), value = 1:6)
df

#  indicator value
#1         X     1
#2         Y     2
#3         X     3
#4         X     4
#5         Y     5
#6         Y     6
```

You can use -

```
df$value[df$indicator == 'X'] <- df$value[df$indicator == 'X'] * -1

df
#  indicator value
#1         X    -1
#2         Y     2
#3         X    -3
#4         X    -4
#5         Y     5
#6         Y     6
```